# PIC24 SPI master mode - generation of slave select?

Tags: embedded, spi, pic24

Can **PIC24** operating as **SPI master** directly generate the **slave-select** signal **in hardware**? 
I know about the Frame Sync feature, however, it only generates a single pulse at the beginning of a frame, not a chip select that is active throughout the whole frame.

If not, which other controller could do that?

Comment: Did you try to download the manual and read it? The SPI chapter is where I would look for the answer.

Comment: SPI does not provide Chip Select signals. Then Embedded SPI modules does not either. Slave selection is made by adresses into the frame.

Comment: I think that's incorrect, SPI uses slave select, maybe confused with I2C which is an address based bus